# JWT and certificate authentication

Tags: php, ssl, certificate, rsa, jwt

A client wants me to connect to a salesforce webservice using oauth2 and JWT on a PHP website on the client's server.

The client sent me a certificate.txt ("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ......",  Key Size 2048) but when I try to generate the JWT and sign it using the certificate and the SHA256 with RSA algo (this algo is mandatory for the webservice), openssl returns an error:

> "supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key"

Here is the code I use:

```
    $binary_signature = "";
    $algo = "SHA256";
    openssl_sign($encodedString, $binary_signature, $certificateContent, $algo);
    print(base64_encode($binary_signature) ."\n");
```

I am new to certificates and I didn't find an answer by reading the web, is the certificate wrong?

Comment: You need the private key, not the certificate. JWT doesn't even use certificates, just public keys and private keys.

Comment: Also, [use a library](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt). It makes life much easier.